# Keep bootstrap modal window open after turbolink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm using twitter bootstrap to open a modal window without using JavaScript:

In my  www.domain.com/item/1 I have

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-custom" data-target="#myModal" >Add to list</a>
```

This triggers the following modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
              <h3 id="myModalLabel">Add to list</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <table>
<% @my_lists.each do |list| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= list.name %></td>
      <td>
          <% if Listing.exists?(:item_id => @item.id, :list_id => list.id) %>
                <i class="icon-check"></i>  
          <% else %>
              <%= link_to listing_list_path(:item =>@item.id, :list=> list.id) do %>
                    <i class="icon-check-empty"></i>    
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
       </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
            </div>
            </div>
```

And in my controller:

```
def listing
  @item = Item.find(params[:item])
  @list = List.find(params[:list])
  @list.add_item(@item)
  redirect_to [:back]
end
```

When I click on listing the item, it gets properly listed but the page goes back to

www.domain.com/item/1

with the modal window closed. I would like it to keep the modal open. I've tried redirecting to www.domain.com/item/1#myModal but that doesn't work.

I'm using rails4 with Turbolinks enabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're not preventing the default behavior on the anchor tag.

Try adding this JavaScript to see if it works

```
$('a[data-toggle=modal]').click (e) -> e.preventDefault()
```